# How do I reduce multiple outputs

Tags: c

How can I limit the output to only one response when I type in multiple characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    char answer;

    printf("Do you want to continue(Y/N)?");
    scanf("%c", &answer);

    while ((answer != 'Y') && (answer != 'N')){
        printf("\nYou must type a Y or an N\n");
        printf("Do you want to continue(Y/N) ?");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use %s format in your scanf and search for 'y' or 'n' with `strchr ()` in the resulting string.

Comment: By using `fgets` to obtain all inputs. If it was invalid in some way, forget it and input another string.

Comment: @Cubo78 how woud I use `strchr ()` ?

Comment: First Google result: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm . It is a function for searching the first occurrence of a char within a string.

Comment: Note: `while ((answer != 'Y') && (answer != 'N')){   ...  scanf(" %c", &answer); }` is an infinite loop on end-of-file.  Better to test the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Generally helpful (though it might read a little cynical at first): http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: `@Yunnosch` The article helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use getchar() for reading the first character, then read next characters until EOF.

Additionaly the reading outside (before) the loop is not necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// additional function for reading remaining input
void flush();

main(){

    // answer needs to be int, because getchar() can return -1 in case of EOF
    int answer; 

    while (1) {

        printf("Do you want to continue(Y/N)? ");
        answer = getchar();

        // read and ignore the remaining input
        flush();

        if ((answer == 'Y') || (answer == 'N'))
            break; // exit loop

        printf("\nYou must type a Y or an N\n");
    }

    // here answer contains 'Y' or 'N'
    // do what you need with this...

    return 0;
}

// function for consuming the remaining input
void flush()
{
    while (getchar() != EOF); // consume input until emptying
}
```